# Ajax function dependency between request and response type

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http-headers, content-type

If I use:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Am I forced to receive a `json` response also ? Or I can receive a `html` response instead?

If I can receive any format I want, what is the best way to dynamically manage this 2 aspects:

1. the way that I will parse the response (to parse a json or not)
2. what `Accept` header to use

For example my function should set:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
```

in case it waits for a json response, but also do a json parse on the response also, but in case it's a html reponse there is no need for something like this.

So is there any way to manage dynamically the response handling?

Answer (score 0):

Actually content-type is the data type you want to send to the server . on the other hand data-type or as you mention accept is used to negotiate with server which kind of data you are expecting . So  as a client you can request multiple data types e.g

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/xml');
```

But you are responsible to handle the data-type you mention  to parse on client side . on server side it is decided by server during negotiation time  to produce your desired data-type such as xml,json ,html etc.

So finally you are you are only responsible for the data format  you requested. if you request json , then probably the server response data will be json not xml but you have to remember it depends on server side which data-type choice it has, most of the time its json or xml (will known data exchange fromat) then you dont have to request html ,and this mechanism is called content negotiation

Answer (score 0):

> Am I forced to receive a json response also?

No. The format of the data you send and the format of the data you receive are unrelated.

> Or I can receive a html response instead?

You can.

> the way that I will parse the response (to parse a json or not)

Read the `Content-Type` response header and use it to determine what format the data is in.

> what Accept header to use

Ask for a data format that you:

- are comfortable parsing and processing
- know that server is able to send